# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.1

Tags: gradle, flutter, build.gradle

I clearly have no clue why it shows this error. All solutions are appreciated.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > Android resource linking failed
  >   Output:  W/ziparchive( 9548): Unable to open 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar': No such file or directory
  >   error: failed to open APK: I/O error.

  Command: C:\Users\admin.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\c8dfbdcc79a1dd8c0cb75349d60f6c77\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        C:\Users\gaurav\tutorial\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        C:\Users\gaurav\tutorial\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @C:\Users\gaurav\tutorial\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        C:\Users\gaurav\tutorial\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.example.tutorial\
        -0\
        apk\
        --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s

---

The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration for more information on the problem and how to fix it.

---

Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

Update you sdk version to 28. Edit the file `build.gradle` and change property `compileSdkVersion` up to 28.